# How do I disable the trackpad on my MacBook Pro using syndaemon?

Tags: mac, macbook, trackpad

I try to run `syndaemon -i 2 -t -d`  to disable the trackpad while typing (detailed in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro7-1/Maverick). However, I am getting

```
No synaptics properties on device 'bcm5974'.
```

Which is weird because I followed all the steps in the guide. My xorg.conf is:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer" EndSection

Section "Files" EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5" EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd" EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS" EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation" EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection EndSection

Section "InputClass"
    MatchIsTouchpad "true"
    Identifier "Multitouch Touchpad"
    Driver "multitouch"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*" EndSection
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to control this behaviour directly from the `Mouse` control panel.  On the `Touchpad` page, there should be a `Disable touchpad while typing` option that does what you want.

Comment: It's buggy and doesn't work. I saw a bug threat on that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`dispad`](https://github.com/BlueDragonX/dispad) to disable the touchpad when typing. It works for me.